# Calculate Coordinates on Arc, Based on Time of Day

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

Hopefully someone can help me out with this.

I'm trying to calculate the position of a point on an arc, based on a percentage of distance along the circumference (% time of day). Sidenote - I'm writing a computer program to execute this, it's just the math that's stopping me!

I know the length of the chord, the height of the saggita, and the coordinates of the circle. I've attached an image as a diagram to explain this.

Based on the time of day, from $6$A.M $(0,0)$ to $6$P.M $(1400,0)$, where will the point on the arc be? Given that $12$P.M the arc will be at coordinates $(700,500)$.

Saggita = $500$,
Chord = $1400$

[image]

Another image, with the things I know and don't, also better illustrating the problem I'm trying to solve.

[image: The Problem Illustrated]

Comment: Do you want the sun to move at a constant rate of arc length per hour or a constant angle per hour?

Comment: Also are the hours evenly spaced on the arc by arclength or are they evenly spaced by angle

Comment: Based on the time, I'd like the point to move along the arc's length. So for 9AM, the coordinates would be moved a total of 25% of the arc's the length.

Comment: I will be calculating this to the minute, so that whenever I input a time, it will go to the exact location along the arc, based the time percentage between 6AM and 6PM. Does that make it clearer? Let me know if I can explain better.

Comment: The best you'll be able to get is an approximation, I can tell you that.

Comment: Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have edited my answer. It now takes in to account the fact that the geometry is a circle not an ellipse and I have fixed my solution. Also it hasn't seemed to have thrown off any answers but I think the far right coordinate should be $(1400,0)$ rather than $(0,1400)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT (If Curve is a Circle):**
An edit must be made if the curve is a shifted down semicircle. Lets assume it is. Then to find its equation we will fit an equation of the form
$$y=\sqrt{R^2-(x-700)^2}+k$$
to the points $(0,0), (700,500),$ and $(1400,0)$. That requires solving a system of equations, but I'll just skip to the fact that the equation for the semi-circle is
$$y=\sqrt{740^2-(x-700)^2}-240$$
Next we want to find what the arc length is from $x=0$ to $1400$. Using calculus,
$$S_1=\int_{0}^{1400}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x-700}{\sqrt{740^2-(x-700)^2}}\right)^2}\text{d}x=1480\arcsin\left(\frac{35}{37}\right)\approx 1835.9$$
Having that done we also want the arc length from $x=1400$ to $1440$, $S_2$, which can be done using geometry and is
$$S_2=\frac{740\pi-S_1}{2}\approx 244.439$$
Now we want to find, based on $m$ minutes that have passed since $6$ A.M. what the interior angle $\theta$ is so that we can use $\sin$ and $\cos$ for the coordinates. Using geometry we can get that the central angle formed by the sun and the point $(1440,-240)$ is given by
$$\theta=\frac{S_1-\frac{S_1\cdot m}{720}+S_2}{R}\approx \frac{1497844.08-1835.9m}{532800}$$
Then having computed $\theta$ given an $m$, the coordinates of the sun are just
$$(740\cos\theta + 700, 740\sin\theta-240)$$
In conclusion using $m$ just find $\theta$ and plug it into the parametrized coordinates. [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pexvgcsnnd)'s a Desmos graph where you can change the value of $m$ and watch the coordinate in red (the sun) move along the circle.

**If Curve is an Ellipse**
What we have here is half an ellipse. The function for that half ellipse is
$$y=500\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x-700}{700}\right)^2}$$
Now we need to find the length of the arc, and for that we will use some calculus. The arc length, $S$, is given by in this case,
$$S=\int_{0}^{1400}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{5(x-700)}{7\sqrt{-x(x-1400)}}\right)^2}\text{d}x$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1400}\sqrt{1-\frac{25(x-700)^2}{49x(x-1400)}}\text{d}x=1898.07$$
Using that, there's a few things that can be said. Let $m$ be the minutes that have passed since 6 A.M., then the arc length that has been covered is given by
$$S_m=\frac{1898.07m}{720}$$
Using that a the following can be done: Given a time compute $S_m$, the amount of arclength that has been covered. Then decide on a threshold $\epsilon>0$, and have you're computer test values until it finds a value $x_0$ such that
$$\left|S_m - \int_{0}^{x_0}\sqrt{1-\frac{25(x-700)^2}{49x(x-1400)}}\text{d}x\right|\le \epsilon$$
Then the coordinates of the sun will be
$$(x_0,y(x_0))$$
where $y$ is as defined above.
I'll work on thinking of a more efficient way to approximate the coordinates, but as of now that's the best I can think of.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Now to get this translated into ruby. Thanks!

Comment: This answer contradicts the OP's statement that the sun appears at a point on the *circle* that passes through the three points $(0,0),(0,1400),(700,500)$, and that we want to find the coordinates of this point relative to the given coordinate system. I've posted a general solution [below](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1715663/16397).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general solution for the situation you describe, pictured below. The question states that the three given points (which I'll call $A,B,C$) are on a circle, and indeed these points determine a *unique* $\color{blue}{circle}$. I consider the problem of finding where on this circle the sun will appear to be (as a function of time), as seen by someone located at the midpoint $O$ of line segment $AB$.

**NB**: $O$ is not the center of the blue circle, but is the center of a $\color{orange}{circle}$ around which the sun will appear (from $O$) to move at (approximately) *constant speed*. Consequently, the sun will appear to move at *varying speeds* around the blue circle.

- $A=(0,0),\ B=(0,2a),\ C=(a,h)$ (Your question is the case $a=700, h=500$.)
- $AB$ is a line segment of length $2a$ with midpoint $O$.
- $C$ is the point at height $h$ on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$.
- The orange circle has radius $a$ and is centered at $O$.
- $P$ is the point on the orange circle such that $O$P is aligned with the sun.
- The blue circle is the *unique* circle that passes through points $A,B,C$. Let $R$ denote its radius. (Note $R> a$ if $a>h$.)
- $P'$ (whose coordinates we want to find) is the point on the blue circle such that $OP'$ is aligned with the sun.

[image]

Solution ...

1. Let $O'$ be the center of the blue circle. By considering the right triangle $AOO'$, $$(R-h)^2 + a^2 = R^2\tag{1}$$ therefore $$R = \frac{a^2+h^2}{2h}\tag{2}$$
2. With time $t$ measured in hours since midnight,$$\theta(t) = \frac{\pi}{12}t - \frac{\pi}{2}\quad(6\le t\le 18)\tag{3}$$ (To get this, set $\theta(t) = c_1 t + c_2$, then determine $c_1,c_2$ by requiring $\theta(6) = 0, \theta(18) = \pi$.)
3. Let $(x_P,y_P)$ be the coordinates of point $P$. By simple trigonometry, $$\begin{align}x_P =& a(1-\cos\theta)\\ y_P =& a\sin\theta\end{align}\tag{4}$$
4. Find the required coordinates $(x,y)$ of point $P'$ by solving two simultaneous equations: The line through $OP$ is described by the equation $$y=\begin{cases}\frac{y_P}{x_P-a}(x-a) && \text{if }x_P\neq a\\ h && \text{if }x_P = a\end{cases}\tag{5}$$ and the blue circle has equation $$(x-a)^2 + ((y+(R-h))^2 = R^2\tag{6}$$  Substituting $y$ from $(5)$ into $(6)$ and solving for $x$, 
   $$x=\begin{cases}
   \frac{a-ST - \sqrt{(a-ST)^2 - (S^2+1)(a^2+T^2-R^2)}}{S^2+1} &&\text{if } \theta < {\pi\over 2} \\
   a         &&\text{if } \theta = {\pi\over 2}\\
   \frac{a-ST + \sqrt{(a-ST)^2 - (S^2+1)(a^2+T^2-R^2)}}{S^2+1} &&\text{if } \theta > {\pi\over 2} \\
   \end{cases}\tag{7}$$
   where
   $$\begin{align}
   S =& \frac{y_P}{x_P-a}\\
   T =& R-h -aS
   \end{align}\tag{8}$$

---

Summarizing: To find the coordinates $(x,y)$ of point $P'$, the steps are
$$t \xrightarrow{Eq(3)}\theta\xrightarrow{Eq(4)}(x_P,y_P)\xrightarrow{Eqs(5,7,8)} (x,y).$$

---

**Example** ($a=700, h=500, R=740$, time = 9:37 AM)
$$\begin{align}
t &= 9 + 37/60 \approx 9.61666666666667\\
\theta &\approx 0.946841119206924\\
P(x_P,y_P) &\approx (291.025234053796, 568.101787375508)\\
P'(x,y) &\approx (389.286724718565,431.607966423778) 
\end{align}$$

Here's a picture for $120$ equally-spaced times ($\delta t = 6$ minutes) spanning the $12$-hour period:

[image]

**NB**: As point $P$ moves around the orange circle at constant speed, point $P'(x,y)$ moves around the blue circle at speeds that vary with time, moving faster near noon and slower near 6 AM and 6 PM. This shows up as a change in the spacing of the plotted points.

Comment: Although this is a good answer it contradicts the fact that the OP wants the sun to move at a constant rate of arc length per minute.

Comment: He may *want* it to be so in comments, but that seems inconsistent with the description he posted in the question. (In the comments, he might not have noticed the inconsistency.)